# how to get all tab urls in another chrome event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I hope implement following code:

```
//background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
  var allTabUrls
  // use chrome.tabs
  getAllTabUrls(function(urls)) {
    allTabUrls = urls
  }
  handleUrls(allTabUrls)
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]})
```

I find all chrome callback is run in asynchronize, so my code will first run `handleUrls(allTabUrls)` before `allTabUrls = urls`, how to wait async function finish and then run `handleUrls(allTabUrls)`

Answer (score 0):

Is the code below your expected it?

```
//background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
  // use chrome.tabs
  getAllTabUrls(function(urls) {
    handleUrls(urls);
  });
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```